# Compare excel data to oracle database c#

Tags: oracle, asp.net-mvc-3, excel, telerik-grid

I have the following requirements:

Read selected columns(DetailsId, SentDate, Count) from excel, get data for the respective DetailsId(s) from Oracle database. Show the comparison data from the excel and database in a grid (MVC).

If the data matches do nothing, if there is a mismatch update some database columns with data in the excel.

Any suggestions how this can be done

Thanks

Comment: There are a variety of ways, built into dotnet, to read excel spreadsheet files.  The rest of this is typical application programming.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Convert your excel spreadsheet to CSV format, define an [external table](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e17118/statements_7002.htm#sthref5226) in Oracle using the CSV file as the source, then compare the external table values with the actual Oracle table using SQL within C# and display results as required. Update data as needed.